# Context Free Language? Proving through grammar?

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

I need help solving this question:

Is $L = \{ w \in \{a,b,c\}^* \mid n_a(w) = n_b(w) = 2n_c(w)\}$ a context-free language? 
That is the number of $a$'s equal the number of $b$'s equal twice the number of $c$'s in the string $w$.

First, I think that the language is context-free, but i'm having trouble finding a context free grammar to prove it.

So far I have:

\begin{align}
S &\to SASBS \mid SBSAS \mid λ \\
A &\to a \\
B &\to b \\
\end{align}

I'm not sure how to get twice the number of $c$'s, could someone please show me/correct me?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** The language is (unfortunately) not context free.  Recall the [Pumping Lemma for context free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages), and suppose that $p$ is the pumping length of $L$.  Now consider the string $w = \mathtt{a}^{2p} \mathtt{b}^{2p} \mathtt{c}^p$.  (Note that no substring of $w$ of length $\leq p$ can contain $\mathtt{a}$s, $\mathtt{b}$s and $\mathtt{c}$s.)